# Are $x, e^{2x}, e^{3x}$ linearly independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've come to the conclusion that these vectors are *linearly independent*.

If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$, then we need to prove

$$ \alpha \cdot x + \beta \cdot e^{2x} + \gamma \cdot e^{3x} = \textbf{0} \ (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) \text{.}$$

Because the domain is infinite ($\mathbb{R}$), I will choose a specific value for $x$ that will help me get a relation between scalars.

For $x = 0$ we get $\beta + \gamma = 0 \Rightarrow \beta = - \gamma$, after which:

$$\alpha \cdot x - \gamma \cdot e^{2x} + \gamma \cdot e^{3x} = \textbf{0}$$
$$\iff \alpha \cdot x = \gamma \cdot e^{2x} \cdot (1-e^x) $$

Because $x \ne e^{2x} \cdot (1-e^x) \land e^{2x} \cdot (1-e^x) \ne 0 \ (\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})$, values of scalars then must be $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$ which means that the vectors are linearly independent.

Is there something incorrect with my solution, and is there maybe a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: The first part is OK, but can you elaborate on the second part? How exactly do you conclude that $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$?

Comment: No, you *don't* need to prove that$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\alpha x+\beta e^{ex}+\gamma e^{3x}=0.$$This assertion is neither true nor false, since you say nothing about $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$. What you need to prove is that if $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are real numbers such that$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\alpha x+\beta e^{ex}+\gamma e^{3x}=0,$$then $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\alpha x+\beta e^{2x}+\gamma e^{3x}$$
If $f(x)\equiv 0$ then $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0.$ Thus $$\beta+\gamma=\alpha+2\beta +3\gamma=4\beta+9\gamma=0$$ which implies $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0.$
Another solution can be made by considering three linear equations, $f(0)=f(1)=f(-1)=0,$ and showing that they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

You proved that $\alpha \cdot x - \gamma \cdot e^{2x} + \gamma \cdot e^{3x} =0$.

Now, if $\alpha\neq 0$, then $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\alpha \cdot x - \gamma \cdot e^{2x} + \gamma \cdot e^{3x} = \pm \infty$ (the sign depending on the sign of $\alpha$). This is absurb if $\alpha \cdot x - \gamma \cdot e^{2x} + \gamma \cdot e^{3x} = 0$ for every $x$, so $\alpha=0$.

Finally, $\gamma e^{2x}(1-e^x)=0$ implies that $\gamma =0$ since $e^{2x}(1-e^x) \neq 0$ for $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithmic approach: Given functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ that are differentiable $n - 1$ times on an interval $I$, if the Wronskian determinant $$W(f_1, \ldots, f_n) := \det \pmatrix{f_1 & \cdots & f_n \\ f_1' & \cdots & f_n' \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ f_1^{(n - 1)} & \cdots & f_n^{(n - 1)}}$$ is nonzero anywhere on $I$, then the functions are linearly independent on $I$.
In our case
$$W(x, e^{2 x}, e^{3 x}) = \det \pmatrix{x & e^{2 x} & e^{3 x} \\ 1 & 2 e^{2 x} & 3 e^{3 x} \\ 0 & 4 e^{2 x} & 9 e^{3 x}} = (6 x - 5) e^{5 x}.$$ So, $W$ vanishes only at $x = \frac{5}{6}$, hence $\{x, e^{2 x}, e^{3 x}\}$ is linearly independent on any open interval. Generalizing this argument shows that $\{x, e^{\alpha x}, e^{\beta x}\}$ is linearly independent whenever $\alpha \neq \beta$.

**Remark** The converse of the above statement about the Wronskian, $W$, is false, e.g., you can find functions $f, g$ such that $W(f, g) = 0$ but $\{f, g\}$ is not linearly dependent. The statement is true, however, if the functions are analytic.